# Morris.js - the line chart not getting displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, morris.js

I am trying to use morris.js to generate line chart. I am following the below railcasts -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBMQTi_SjfU

I have a controller, greetings with method hello. I am using the below example for morris's site.

http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?js,output

As per the instruction in video, I have - 
1. downloaded uncompressed version of morris and raphael and added to /vendor/assets/javascripts
2. included "/= require raphael & /=require morris" in application.js
3. copied the morris' example to greetings.js.coffee and changed the code to coffeescript

```
jQuery ->

Morris.Line
  element: 'line-example'
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 ,
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 }
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 }
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 }
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 }
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 }
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ]
  xkey: 'y'
  ykeys: ['a', 'b']
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
```

4. added a div tag in hello.html.erb with id='line-example'

However I am not getting the chart. I checked the source of webpage and it shows the script.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Do you use exactly this indents in your original coffee code?

Answer (score 0):

The indentation was not correct at one place, hence the graph was not working.